# Error: uploading files for distribution UNRELEASED to ppa not allowed

Tags: launchpad

I have been trying to upload to my launchpad ppa for the first time, I did everything as instructed, used debuild to generate a changes file, all messages indicated a success, signed the changes file with my GPG key which I am using on the ppa.
however, when I do the final step which is uploading using the following command:

```
dput ppa:alyshmahell/<archive> <source.changes>
```

I'm getting this Error:

```
uploading files for distribution UNRELEASED to ppa not allowed.
```

Any Idea to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I was building for a Debian distribution while I am in fact targeting Ubuntu. rookie mistake.

The solution was to edit the "changelog" file in the Debian folder and substitute "UNRELEASED" for "xenial".